# Direct HTTP to HTTPS behind a Proxy in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a server written in Spring Boot (2.0.5). It's behind a Proxy server that provides SSL. The proxy accepts both HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) and forwards both to my server which only accepts HTTP on port 2222. The proxy set the following request headers.

- x-forwarded-for
- x-forwarded-proto
- x-forwarded-port

I tested the following code in `WebSecurityConfig` class and it didn't work.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
     httpSecurity.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
     .and().
     ...  
}
```

I also wrote the following code to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. But it redirects HTTPS traffic too. But I only need to redirect HTTP.

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityCollection;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class HttpsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {

            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        return tomcat;
    }
}
```

I am searching for a way to check out the request headers and if it's HTTP I want to redirect it to HTTPS.

Answer (score 4):

The Spring Security configuration you provided should work. I'm guessing that the problem is that you haven't [set up Spring Boot to work with proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server) correctly. To enable the support, you should specify:

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
```

NOTE: If your application runs in Cloud Foundry or Heroku, the server.use-forward-headers property defaults to true. In all other instances, it defaults to false.

I'd pay particularly close attention to the [details around Tomcat](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server). This is what causes most people problems. Tomcat relies on an additional setting to determine if the internal proxy IP address matches a default regex. If your proxy's IP doesn't match the regex, it silently ignores the forwarded headers.

If you are struggling with this aspect, try specifying the following:

```
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=.*
```

NOTE: Other application servers don't care about the proxy IP address and if the client can spoof the X Forwarded headers then it can also spoof the IP Address, so opening this up to every IP address should not have an impact on your application.

Comment: These properties are only valid for the embedded tomcat server, right?

Comment: FYI - As of Spring Boot 2.2 the property was deprecated. [2.2 Release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#deprecations-in-spring-boot-22) [Stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126518/how-to-cope-with-x-forwarded-headers-in-spring-boot-2-2-0-spring-web-mvc-behin)